# Disabling Modal Dialogs for List Forms in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to set the list setting "Launch forms in dialog" to 'No' via the List definition?

I have a custom list definition that I create in visual studio, i'd like to set the setting once so that i can easily deploy and create my list without manually setting this option.

Answer (score 6):

Andy had the right attribute, just the wrong value. It should be:

NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE"

This will disable launching of forms in a dialog.

Answer (score 5):

In the  tag for your definition you need to add the attribute:

```
NavigateForFormsPages="FALSE"
```

This doesn't appear to be in the online CAML documentation.

FYI, there also seems to be a property for choosing what application should open the document:

```
BrowserFileHandling="permissive"
```

I found this by saving a list as a template, downloading the STP file, changing the extension to a .cab, extracting and reviewing the manifest file.

The relevant line was:

```
<List Name="{AFB613BE-5A3E-47FB-989C-FD4FB060AEE8}" Title="test" Description="" Direction="0" BaseType="0" FeatureId="{00BFEA71-DE22-43B2-A848-C05709900100}" ServerTemplate="100" Url="Lists/test" FolderCreation="FALSE" NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE" BrowserFileHandling="permissive" Version="1">
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i'll try it now and let you know how i got on

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( I added the properties to my list definition,    <List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Lists - MarketPlace" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Lists-MarketPlace" 
      BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" NavigateForFormsPages="FALSE" DisableAttachments="true" BrowserFileHandling="permissive"> but visual studio has highlighted the attributes as not declared and the forms are still opening in popup

Comment: Don't worry Visual Studio highlighting - I just saved my test site as a WSP, and imported it into VS2010, and looking at the schema for that list it a) has those properties again, and b) they're underlined here too. Having created the WSP for the whole site, the first line of the schema.xml is as below. Could the problem be elsewhere in the schema?

Comment: <List Title="list" Direction="none" Url="Lists/list" BaseType="0" Type="100" BrowserFileHandling="permissive" NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Catalog="FALSE" SendToLocation="|" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itgen.png" xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" xmlns:spctf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">